# how to do logging in Django 1.9

Tags: python, django, logging

## Software

- Django 1.9
- Python 3.4
- Postgres 9.x

## What happened

I am using the below code in Django 1.9

```
from django.db import connection
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT .... WHERE ... GROUP BY p.id')
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

I wanted to see the rows in a log file

## What I did try

I copied pasted from the documentation into my settings.py the following

```
import logging.config
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(DJANGO_ROOT, 'WIT.log')
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

## What's the problem?

After that I am stuck as to how do I log that particular `rows`. Can help?

Comment: Do you want to log every row? Just import logging; logger = logging.getLogger(__name__); In a loop call logger.info(each_row_data), is there another problem which I miss-understood?

Comment: Is there a way, i can simply logger.info(rows) instead of writing a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically all you need to do now is **start writing messages to the logger**, some thing like @Serjik suggested:

```
logger.info(each_row_data)
```

### A little bit of theory

[Logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/logging/) DJANGO consists of four part:

- **Logger**: the entry point into the logging system
- **Handlers**: engines that determines what happens to each message in a logger
- **Filters**: A filter is used to provide additional control over which log records are passed from logger to handler.
- **Formatters**: describe the exact format of the logs.

What you have done actually is declaring the **Handler** but now you need to an instance of the logger where you can writer yours log, which then will be handler by the Handler.

#### Loggin an information

```
# Get an instance of a logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.error('Something went wrong!')
```

#### Declaring an handler that writes to a local file

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/path/to/django/debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I now have a new issue. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40582796/logging-does-not-show-the-result