# logging does not show the result of array

Tags: python, django, logging

## Software

- Django 1.9
- Python 3.4

## What did I do?

I have the following Django code in my views.py

```
from django.db import connection
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT p.name, p.name_zh_hans, p.art_number, ....')
    rows = cursor.fetchall()

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

for row in rows:
        row_num += 1
        logger.info(row)
        for col_num in range(len(row)):
            ws.write(row_num, col_num, row[col_num], font_style)
```

## What did I get inside the log file?

```
(0.005) SELECT p.name, p.name_zh_hans, p.art_number, ....; args=None
(0.005) SELECT p.name, p.name_zh_hans, p.art_number, ....; args=None
(0.006) SELECT p.name, p.name_zh_hans, p.art_number, ....; args=None
```

## What did I expect?

Display of the array contents inside the log file

**What went wrong?**

Comment: Where did you configure the logging? Why are you using pure SQL in Django?

Comment: Can you please tell us how many rows do you have in your table? I need to know it for being sure about what I think :)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)` before you call `logging.getLogger(__name__)`.

You can check out the [Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/logging-cookbook.html) for a detailed guide.

Answer (score 0):

I belive that what you are seeing are actually logs from **django.db.backends**, checkout [this reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/logging/#django-db-backends).

> Messages relating to the interaction of code with the database. For
>   example, every application-level SQL statement executed by a request
>   is logged at the DEBUG level to this logger.
>
> Messages to this logger have the following extra context:
>
> **duration**: The time taken to execute the SQL statement. 
>  
>   **sql**: The SQL 
>   statement that was executed. 
> **params**: The parameters that were used in
>   the SQL call. 
> For performance reasons, SQL logging is only enabled
>   when settings.DEBUG is set to True, regardless of the logging level or
>   handlers that are installed.
>
> This logging does not include framework-level initialization (e.g. SET
>   TIMEZONE) or transaction management queries (e.g. BEGIN, COMMIT, and
>   ROLLBACK). Turn on query logging in your database if you wish to view
>   all database queries.

You are logging with level **log level info** meanwhile **django.db.backends** logs at **DEBUG** level so checkout also your log handlers to be sure what you are actually logging and what you are not :)

Hope it helps!